# Minutos atras en Date() javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hola tengo este formato de tiempo SSSZ ISO, y quiero generar una variable con el tiempo por ejemplo 4 minutos atrás. Como puedo implementar esto en javascript.

```
let timeNow = new Date(
   new Date().toString().split("GMT")[0] + " UTC"
 ).toISOString();
```

Aquí quiero optener el tiempo a partir del timeNow pero  4 min atrás

```
timeFourMinAgo = ?
```

Comment: Réstale 4 min * 60 seg * 1000 milisegundos: `new Date(new Date()-240000)`

Comment: Hola Sal tu solución me esta dando esta salida para el tiempo ahora y el tiempo 4 minutos atrás: 2021-05-25T19:35:50.000Z, 2021-05-26T00:31:50.232Z. y veo que hay diferencias en la fecha y en el tiempo como 25 - 26 (dia) y 19 - 00 (hora)

Comment: Asumo que cualquier conversión a cadena la haces al último.

Comment: Mismo resultado sin conversiones de cadena 2021-05-26T00:57:44.467Z

Answer (score 2):

Tu fecha conviértela a milisegundos, réstale 4 min * 60 seg * 1000 milisegundos=240000, y vuelve a obtener la fecha, por último el formato que prefieras:

```js
const today = new Date();  
const time=today.getTime()-240000;
const timeFourMinAgo = new Date(time);

console.log("Ahora: ",today);
console.log("4 minutos atras: ",timeFourMinAgo);
```